# Finding the right SQL report

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-agent, ssms-2014

I know that I've used it before but I cannot find it now.

I have several SQL Server Agent jobs that run. Some of them fail, but the error messages in the History are not very helpful. I found a report that helped, but now I cannot remember where I found it exactly.

I know that I right-clicked => Reports => Standard Reports => All Execution?

I'm not sure about the last step or where the first step is supposed to be.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe SSMS -> Integration Services Catalog -> SSISDB -> Reports -> Standard Reports-> All Executions?

Comment: @lad2025 That was it!! I've been searching for almost an hour and couldn't remember where it was. Thanks! Put that in an answer and I'll mark it done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your SQL Agent Job runs SSIS package.

To get detailed info use:

SSMS -> Integration Services Catalog -> SSISDB -> RC -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> All Executions